# Adding new dropbox.framework to xcode giving error

Tags: xcode, frameworks, dropbox

I have tried to add dropbox framework to my xcode 4.5 but I'm getting an error as follows

**ld: 14 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

So I googled for it and found ,xcode 4.5 no longer supports drop box framework. So I tried to add new 1.3 version of dropbox framework but still it gives the same error.Please help me out. How to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

First try to clean the project first and try to run it again. If not, have you looked at this: http://www.mathiastauber.com/integration-o-dropbox-in-your-ios-application/

Comment: @MacNOOb You are no longer Mac N00b !! ;)

Comment: If that worked, you should mark my answer as correct so that others that come to this question will know it is the correct answer.

Comment: I followed the tutorial no help . getting same error . I guess i need to work on the mailing feature which i have added to my app.